# how to connect use openVPN

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a Android app with rosjava, he can control the robot within the same network.Now I want to control robots that are not in the same network through openVPN. It can connect but  the app sent the topic robot can not receive.Why is that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275708/how-to-connect-use-openvpn/) by [Min.Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/32605/min.chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-11-13**:
This could be a number of things. I'd read the [network setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) tutorial and make sure it's correct. Also, ensure the routing is set correctly in your VPN and there aren't any firewalls in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a good question with answers on how to setup an openvpn here: https://answers.ros.org/question/11045/how-to-set-up-vpn-between-ros-machines/

To use your android you'll likely need to connect it to a gateway that's forwarding the local network over the vpn.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0